# OpenCMIS TCK test troubleshooting

Tags: cmis, opencmis

I'm implementing a CMIS server using OpenCMIS.
I use TCK tests to check CMIS compliance. The error messages of the compliance checks are very short. There is no info about the call sequence or at least the last call that causes the compliance failure.
Is there a setting to output the used calls or a stack trace or any more informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCK text report contains the stack traces. The stack traces are also in the HTML report, but as comments.

To find out what went wrong you have to look at the code of the TCK tests. The tests are usually short and easy to understand.